# How to push a code to use as much CPU resources as possible?

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, mapreduce

I have a very large set of text files. The task was to calculate the document frequencies (number of document that contain a certain term) for all the terms (uniquely) inside this huge corpus. Simply starting from the first file and calculating everything in a serialized manner seemed to be a dumb thing to do (I admit I did it just to see how disastrous it is).
I realized that if I do this calculation in a Map-Reduce manner, meaning clustering my data into smaller pieces and in the end aggregating the results, I would get the results much faster.

My PC has 4 cores, so I decided to separate my data into 3 distinct subsets and feeding each subset to a separate thread waiting for all the threads to finish their work and passing their results to a another method to aggregate everything.

I tests it with a very small set of data, worked fined. Before I use the actual data, I tested it with a larger set to I can study its behaviour better. I started jvisualvm and htop to see how the cpu and memory is working. I can see that 3 threads are running and cpu cores are also busy. But the usage of these cores are rarely above 50%. This means that my application is not really using the full power of my PC. is this related to my code, or is this how it is supposed to be. My expectation was that each thread uses as much cpu core resource as possible.

I use Ubuntu.

Comment: Did you check I/O counters? Your CPU may be pretty free but your I/O subsystem may be terribly busy (= try to read ahead your data).

Comment: The use of your cpus is managed by your operating system, what OS are you using?

Answer (score 3):

Sounds to me that you have an IO bound application.  You are spending more time in your individual threads *reading* the data from the disk then you are actually processing the information that is read.

You can test this by migrating your program to another system with a SSD to see if the CPU performance changes.  You can also read in all of the files and then process them later to see if that changes the CPU curve during processing time.  I suspect it will.

Comment: maybe, before to buy an SSD, he can try a ramdrive.

Answer (score 2):

As already stated you're bottle-necked by something probably disk IO. Try separating the code that reads from disk from the code that processes the data, and use separate thread pools for each. Afterwards, a good way to quickly scale your thread pools to properly fit your resources is to use one of the [Executors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html) thread pools.

Answer (score 1):

You are IO bound for a problem like this on a single machine, not CPU bound. Are you actively reading the files? Only if you had all the files in-memory would you start to saturate the CPU. That is why map-reduce is effective. It scales the total IO throughput more than CPU.

Answer (score 0):

You can possibly speed up this quite a bit if you are on Linux and use tmpfs for storing the data in memory, instead on disk.